# how to create / add new table in an existing cloudant nosql database

Tags: nosql, ibm-cloud, cloudant

can anyone please tell me if there is a way to add multiple tables into an existing database in the Cloudant nosql database service in IBM Bluemix? As far is i can see in the dashboard there is a way to add only new documents but no new tables.

this is how the dashboard looks:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LJEy.png)

let me know if you need any more details,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Cloudant is a NoSQL, document-oriented database](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/basics/index.html#cloudant-basics) and does not have any tables. There isn't even a schema. Thus, each document stands on its own. You can add multiple documents using the same JSON document / data structure, or many documents of different structure.

Having documents with different structure would be similar to having multiple tables.

Cloudant is based on [CouchDB](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/), a scalable, fault-tolerant, and schema-free document-oriented database. I recommend reading over this [technical background document](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/intro/overview.html).

Comment: i think that you are not correct, when i create a database it comes with one table and that table holds all documents. With Cloudant all documents are related with the revision value thus a document cannot stand on its own.

Comment: The documents in the database are presented in that table in the dashboard. The database itself does not have tables.

Comment: hmmm... that is interesting @data_henrik so what are my options if i need multiple tables? Should i just create new databses for each table that i need?

Comment: see the extended answer

Comment: Stop thinking in terms of "tables" -- you'll have a miserable time with CouchDB/Cloudant. No tables, no explicit schema, no joins, no transactions, only documents. If you need to distinguish between different types of documents in a database, add something like a "doctype" field to your json.